# I Broke My Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

So.. I'm having the hardest time learning how to Promise.

I'm using `bluebird` (https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) as suggested to me -- in order to tame my callback hell I've been getting. Example:

```
function login(req,res,con,mysql,P) {
var ref = undefined;
    con.getConnection(function(err,connection) {
        if (err) console.log("Get Connection Error.. "+err);
        con.query('SELECT password,id FROM player WHERE name='+mysql.escape(req.body.user),function(err,rows,fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (!rows[0]) {
                res.send({
                    "msg":"Your username and or password was incorrect.",
                    "flag":true,
                    "title":": Login Failed"
                });
            }
            if (rows[0].password !== "undefined") {
                if (hash.verify(req.body.pass,rows[0].password)) {
                    req.session.loggedIn = true;
                    req.session.user = rows[0].id;
                    ref = new P(rows[0].id,con,req);
                    res.send({
                        "msg":"You have logged in!",
                        "flag":false,
                        "title":": Logged In"
                    });
                } else {
                    res.send({
                        "msg":"Your username and or password was incorrect.",
                        "flag":true,
                        "title":": Login Failed"
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        connection.release();
    });
    console.log(ref);
    return ref;
}
```

It's nasty, it's full of callbacks, and the function returns `ref` before the query callback is finished executing.

Solution: promises!

I tried to convert my function using the quick start.. so I `promisefyAll`'d my `mysql` module before creating the connection:

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var Promise = require("bluebird");
Promise.promisifyAll(mysql);
```

And I wrote my function as follows:

```
function login(req,res,con,mysql,P) {
    var ref = undefined;
    Promise.promisify(con.getConnection)().then(function(connection) { //updated line returns error no method promisify. Bluebird v. 1.1.1
        con.query('SELECT password,id FROM player WHERE name='+mysql.escape(req.body.user)).then(function(rows,fields) {
            if (hash.verify(req.body.pass,rows[0].password)) {
                req.session.loggedIn = true;
                req.session.user = rows[0].id;
                ref = new P(rows[0].id,con,req);
                res.send({
                    "msg":"You have logged in!",
                    "flag":false,
                    "title":": Logged In"
                });
            } else {
                res.send({
                    "msg":"Your username and or password was incorrect.",
                    "flag":true,
                    "title":": Login Failed"
                });
            }
        });
        return ref;
    });
}
```

But I keep getting `TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined at Object.login (/var/www/post/posts.js:36:22)`

And

`TypeError: undefined is not a function at Pool.<anonymous> (/var/www/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:53:14)`

Errors. Can somebody help me understand how to implement promises for querying my database (correctly)?

Edit (post answer acceptance:): here is how I call the login function:

```
app.post("/login",function(req,res) {
    Player = post.login(req,res,con,mysql,p);
    console.log(Player); // logs [Object object]
}); //inside the login function, it logs the object like it should
```

Comment: Try tying a string around your finger. I find it helps in reminding you to keep promises.

Comment: try reading this: http://howtonode.org/promises (edited ... sorry wrong paste)

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto I linked to that in my question.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto I've read that one as well -- conceptually it makes sense but using a different promise library in a different scenario is different.

Comment: Downvoter -- reason? I'd love to improve this question.

Comment: @RUJordan What does `con.getConnection()` return? Can you try `console.log`gin it?

Comment: First error is because con.getConnection() is not returning a promise.

Comment: @thefourtheye that yields `undefined`. But it works perfectly (minus the object return) in the cluttered, nasty function I'm trying to re-work.

Comment: +1 just for the title

Comment: Don't forget that you are leaking the connection if your query fails :p

Comment: -1 for the *completely unhelpful* title (and I'm not reading the question to figure out a better one)

Comment: @GeorgeJempty what you do is up to you, but downvotes are content quality based, not title based. ;)

Comment: @RUJordan tell that to Adam and the 7 who upvoted his comment

Comment: An upvoted comment doesn't mean all of them upvoted just because of the title. It could very well mean they found the title clever, and the question worthy. Does it really matter that much to you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you promisify a prototype, the promise returning methods will have *Async suffix

The idea of promisification is to pretend as if the library was designed to return promises to begin with. You should not call promisify in application code during runtime, but in your appliation bootstrap init code or similar.

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var Promise = require("bluebird");
//Only need to be called once per application so probably not here
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mysql/lib/Connection").prototype);
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mysql/lib/Pool").prototype);

function login(req,res,con,mysql,P) {
    return con.getConnectionAsync().then(function(connection) {
        return connection.queryAsync('SELECT password,id FROM player WHERE name='+
               mysql.escape(req.body.user)).spread(function(rows, fields) {
            if (hash.verify(req.body.pass,rows[0].password)) {
                req.session.loggedIn = true;
                req.session.user = rows[0].id;
                var ref = new P(rows[0].id,con,req);
                res.send({
                    "msg":"You have logged in!",
                    "flag":false,
                    "title":": Logged In"
                });
                return ref;
            } else {
                res.send({
                    "msg":"Your username and or password was incorrect.",
                    "flag":true,
                    "title":": Login Failed"
                });
            }
        }).finally(function() {
            connection.release();
        });
    });
}
```

---

A future version will have much better resource management and you will be able to do:

```
function login(req,res,con,mysql,P) {
    return Promise.using(con.getConnectionAsync(), function(connection) {
        return connection.queryAsync('SELECT password,id FROM player WHERE name='+
               mysql.escape(req.body.user));
    }).spread(function(rows, fields) {
        if (hash.verify(req.body.pass,rows[0].password)) {
            req.session.loggedIn = true;
            req.session.user = rows[0].id;
            var ref = new P(rows[0].id,con,req);
            res.send({
                "msg":"You have logged in!",
                "flag":false,
                "title":": Logged In"
            });
            return ref;
        } else {
            res.send({
                "msg":"Your username and or password was incorrect.",
                "flag":true,
                "title":": Login Failed"
            });
        }
    });
}
```

---

How to use the result:

```
app.post("/login",function(req,res) {
    post.login(req,res,con,mysql,p).then(function(Player) {

    }); 
})
```

Comment: But if he is using only two or three methods, why should he do `promisifyAll`? `promisify` should have been enough, right?

Comment: @thefourtheye You should always do promisifyAll because then you don't need to worry about it anywhere. It is also faster to call methods that are promisified with promisifyAll

Comment: @Esailija thank you so much. This was literally a copy paste work. Could you please, if it's not too much trouble, link me to resources that explain this so I can learn what spread does etc?

Comment: @RUJordan have you read the [readme](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird#topics) and [API documentation](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md)?

Comment: @Esailija I'll give it another shot. Method by method this time. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @Esailija when I call this login function, I'm returning the object to a variable in my server file -- but I keep getting an empty object returned. But when I log `ref` before it's returned, it logs fine. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Of course, I edited my question. Thank you for going above and beyond to look at this.

Comment: @RUJordan the `login` function returns a promise, so it should log `[object Promise]`

Comment: @Esailija Mmm, it says `[object Object]` not promise. =x

Comment: @RUJordan weird, maybe node logs promises that way too. Anyway the function doesn't return a value but a promise. I have edited how to call login function

Comment: @Esailija brilliant. I can't thank you enough for that!