# Promises in bluebird to control function order

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, server-side, bluebird

I've been trying to understand promises for the server side for the last few days, but I've yet to find anything to work. [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) however seems to be a good alternative. Following the [API](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#thenfunction-fulfilledhandler--function-rejectedhandler----promise) I've tried to test it out but I get an error of: "Cannot call method 'then' of undefined". I looked for [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643061/i-broke-my-promise) errors but I couldn't make mine work similarly.

This is my attempt with bluebird so far:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird')
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request');

// do I need this?
// var request = Promise.promisify(require('request'));
// Promise.promisifyAll(request);

function getA() {
    $(path).each(function(i,e){
        link = $(this).attr("href");
        getB(...).then(function(urls) {
            console.log('type of urls: ' + typeof(urls) + urls);
            // getC();
        }).then(function(urls) {
            // getD();
        });
    });
}

function getB() {
    return new Promise(function(fullfill, reject) {
        request(selectedShow, function (err, resp, page) {      
            if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
                var $ = cheerio.load(page);
                $(path).each(function(i,e){
                    stuff.push($(this).text());
                }
            }); // end each loop
        } // end error and status check
        fullfill(stuff);
    }); // end request
}

function getC() {
    // use 'stuff' array to make requests and fill another array
}   

function getD() {
    // use the arrays to build an object
}
```

Comment: You should `return keep` from `getB`

Comment: Bluebird is *not* an alternative for promises. And there's no alternative to understanding it before using it :-)

Comment: @thefourtheye You're right, I had that earlier but tried to save it as a variable for another test and forgot to change it back.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note, you should return the promise in function `getB`.

Second, you're fulfilling the promise too early. Rather you should fulfill/reject after you get a response from your request:

```
function getB() {
  return new Promise(function(fullfill, reject) {

    request(selectedShow, function(err, resp, page) {

      // at this point you have a response could be error/success
      if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {

        var $ = cheerio.load(page);

        $(path).each(function(i, e) {
          stuff.push($(this).text());
        });

        // fulfill here, since success
        fullfill(stuff);
      } else {
         reject("error"); // usually reject on error
      }
    });

    // TOO EARLY, COS YOU DON'T HAVE A RESPONSE YET!
    // fullfill(stuff);

  }); // end request
}
```

I don't expect this answer to absolutely resolve your issue, but it should help though. Feel free to ask for additional direction after applying the change above.

---

**To answer OP's questions in the comments to this answer**

You have to modify your implementation of `getA` to the following effect:

```
function getA() {
    $(path).each(function(i,e){
        link = $(this).attr("href");
        getB(...).then(function(urls) {
            // NOTE: the `urls` parameter will have same value as the
            // `stuff` used in calling `fulfill(stuff)`
            console.log('type of urls: ' + typeof(urls) + urls);
            // getC();
            // you may also call getD() here
        }).then(function(urls) {
            // this additional `.then()` chain is not necessary as you could
            // have done what it is you wanted to do here inside the first `then(...)`
            // getD();
        });
    });
}
```

Now about the order of execution; putting everything together - your original code snippet and applying changes I made to it in this answer...

When you call `getA()`, that will in turn call `getB()` and after `getB()` executes *successfully* **then** `getC()` and `getD()` will be executed *respectively*. In summary, the order is `getA()` --> `getB()` --if getB() executed with a successful outcome--> `getC()` --> `getC()`.

Now let's define two other functions `getWhatever` and `ohNo`:

```
function getWhatever(){
    console.log("whateeveeer!");
}

function ohNo(){
    console.log("eeeeew!");
}
```

We will modify `getA` a bit:

```
function getA() {
    $(path).each(function(i,e){
        link = $(this).attr("href");
        getB(...).then(function(urls) {
            console.log('type of urls: ' + typeof(urls) + urls);
            getC();
        }).then(function(urls) {
            getD();
        }).catch(function(){
            // you only reach this point if the outcome of getB was an error
            ohNo();
        });

        getWhatever();
    });
}
```

With this new change to `getA` here are the orders of execution for different outcomes:

- when outcome of `getB` is success:

  `getA()` --> `getB()` --> `getWhatever()` --> `getC()`--> `getD()`
- when outcome of `getB` is success:

  `getA()` --> `getB()` --> `getWhatever()` --> `ohNo()`

I hope all your concerns are now addressed fully.

Comment: This did fix the issue I was having with promises giving an error. However, I still am having a problem with order, which is what I looked into promises for.

Comment: When I'm calling getD() with the object it has already looped through all the other items and all my objects being pushed have the same object name ('link' in my example).

Comment: @user147910 I have update my answer to address your comment above. Meanwhile, as you noted that my answer "did fix the issue" you were having, consider accepting it as the answer to your question.